# JPA Pessimistic locking

Tags: java-ee, java

Добрый вечер!
Pessimistic lock READ устроен так, что
как только вы вызвали `entityManager.lock(sample, READ)`, то соответствующая строка в БД блокируется от изменений, но не от чтения.

Я не понимаю как работает pessimistic locking WRITE.И как они связаны с 3 проблемами параллельного доступа к БД(dirty read, unrepeatable read, phantom record).

PS потерянное обновление не в счет

Объясните сабж, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dirty read, unrepeatable read, phantom record - это не про lock, а про [уровни изоляции транзакций](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9).

Пессимистичная блокировка же работает так, что пока транзакция с блокировкой не будет коммитнута или отменена, никакая другая транзакция не сможет произвести запись в эту строку/таблицу.

По сути работа этой блокировки похожа на блокировку в языке Java в многопоточном окружении.

Comment: насщет изоляции я знал. Но описанные мною проблемы изоляции как-то все таки связаны. И по-мойму там сложнее логика работы  этой блокировки. Вот тут написано многабукаф, которые я не понимаю((
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657124/whats-the-difference-between-pessimistic-read-and-pessimistic-write#1657124

Comment: @voipp нет, не связаны. Речь идет о семантике. Там ниже есть замечательная таблица, которая все ставит на свои места.

Comment: @a_gure - да , я знаю эту таблицу.

Answer (score 0):

PESSIMISTIC__READ - при наложении , запись блокируется от изенений , но не от чтения.При этом никто не должен блокировать на запись строку.

PESSIMISTIC__WRITE - при наложении, запись полностью блокируется.Строка не должна быть заблокирована.
Persistence provider может запросить write lock , когда уже имеется read lock, но не наоборот.

PS Read\Write блокировка втсречается не только в БД, но и в EJB Container-managed concurrency

Comment: ReadWriteLock встречается там, где его реализует разработчик. Чем вас не устраивает первый ответ?

Comment: @a_gura ладно, ладно защитал ответ) Но что значит, реализует сам разработчик? как он может это сделать?

Comment: @voipp Взять и сделать :) См. для примера исходники класса `ReentrantReadWriteLock`.